# Canon 5D Mark IV says battery is full, dies in 2-3 minutes, both battery chargers show battery as full

Tags: battery

I have a Canon EOS 5D Mark IV, along with 2 original Canon batteries, 2 aftermarket batteries, and 2 chargers (the original one and an aftermarket one that charges 2 batteries at the same time).

For whatever reason, every time I take a battery out of my Canon, the "replacement" one that I pop up always seem to never really work properly.

For example, I can shoot footage for about 80-90 minutes. As soon as the battery dies, I pop in the next one. The camera shows it full, but then the battery dies in about 2-3 minutes. I thought it was perhaps due to an aftermarket battery or charger, but this seems to be the case even with the original Canon battery and the original charger. It doesn't matter what battery goes first, the second battery that goes in seem to have the issue.

All of this equipment was purchased about 5 years ago.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How old are the batteries?  What is your usage pattern?  Have you tried new ones?

Comment: Sounds like a bit like overheating because “footage” for n-minutes and not tied to specific batteries.

Comment: Gotcha. Very interesting. I've seen it turn off yesterday for temperature issue, but didn't know if perhaps this battery indicator is somewhat related

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: What happens if you wait an hour or so and then try to use the same second battery? Does the camera show it mostly charged, or almost empty?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the camera is just shutting down; the camera is not showing the batteries as being dead/dying prior, they still read as charged by the chargers, and they will function normally after the camera resets.

The note in the owner's manual (pg. 359) highlights this potential issue.
Are you getting the temperature warning icon (pg. 391)?

[image]

Comment: A google suggested that slower memory cards when shooting 4k can contribute to the behavior.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, if it was the card(s) they wouldn't likely get over an hour recorded before it happens. Cards are typically either compatible, or not.

Comment: The Google for for 5d iv overheating suggested cards as a factor. Sustained data rates versus advertised write speed. The symptoms were similar to what is described in the question and the discussions seemed plausibly informed and positively resolved. I am not making an argument. Your answer is good and I upvoted it. As noted in my comment on the question, I think it is overheating electronics. There’s empirical evidence on the internet that the card can cause it. I mentioned it as something that might avoid  mystery overheating. YMMV

Comment: Sure, higher data rates/processing demands would contribute to overheating sooner I would think.